# How to show a ARPlaneGeometry in RealityKit, without using SceneKit?

Tags: ios, swift, realitykit

Consider the default Augmented Realiy app created by Xcode.

`ARSession` has this delegate method called

```
func session(_ session: ARSession, didAdd anchors: [ARAnchor]) {
```

that triggers when a new anchor is added to the scene.

The anchor is an `ARPlaneAnchor`.

This anchor has a geometry property that is an `ARPlaneGeometry` that has nothing to do with the tradicional `ARSPlaneAhchor`.

Because there is zero documentation about it, I ask: this geometry corresponds to a triangle mesh that corresponds to the plane detected by `RealityKit`.

How do I display that mesh on the scene?

Remember that I am using `ARView` not `SceneKit` or other stuff.